# Excel add weekly total and daily totals on same graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a finance sheet that tracks all of my expenditures and totals over time. It has a dashboard with a graph that shows the running total on a weekly basis. I also have one that is the running total on a daily basis. However, I can't combine both of these onto the same graph space as Excel keeps assuming that I want to complete a 1:1 relationship between the plots and thus compresses the weekly data into the first ~52 days of the daily plot.

How can I put multiple time scales onto an Excel graph so that it can show data at two different intervals on it without odd compressions?

[image: This is what occurs. The x-axis is the date (custom format)]

Cheers

Comment: Please share some sample data along with the graph you have created so far, help us to fix the issue.

Comment: My mistake. I've added an image that shows the problem.

Comment: like weekly,,, create month Total & add new data series to graph.

Comment: All adding a montly would do is compress all of the weekly data down even further. The problem is that the second point of the weekly is falling on the 2/7/19 instead of 8/7/19 like it should be. Same with the next point

Answer (score 0):

Add two more columns to your main table, titled **Week number** and **Weekly total**.

In the **Week number** column enter the formula `=WEEKNUM([@[Date days]])` (you might need a second argument to this function to specify the first day of the week).

In the **Weekly total** column enter the formula `=SUMIF([Week number],[@[Week number]],[Number])`. This will then provide your totals, shown against each day, but for the whole week.

You can then incorporate the **Weekly total** column into your chart.